# Insert HTML wrapper after every third in while loop in php

Tags: php, html

I have some 'html' contents to display in `php` while loop. However, I want to have only 3 content blocks in every row and rendered `html` should be something like below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>  
  <div>Content Block</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>
  <div>Content Block</div>
</div>
```

This is how I tried it:

```
$output=[];    
$i=0; 
$html='';
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {    

  if($i % 3 == 0) {
    $html .= "<div class='row'>\n";
  }

  $html.="<div class='col-sm-4'>
            <div class='room-box'>
              <img src='$thumb' class='img-responsive' >
              <h4>$name</h4>
            </div>
          </div>\n";

  if($i++ % 3 == 2) { 
    $html .= "</div>\n";
    $output[] = $html;
  }
}
```

But its not working for me. Can anybody tell me What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: What are you getting so far with the code you're testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to reset the `$html = '';` in the while loop after you have added it to the `$output=[];`

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

    if($i % 3 === 0) {
        $html .= "<div class='row'>\n";
    }

    $html.="<div class='col-sm-4'>
            <div class='room-box'>
              <img src='$thumb' class='img-responsive' >
              <h4>$name</h4>
            </div>
          </div>\n";

    if($i++ % 3 === 2) {
        $html .= "</div>\n";
        $output[] = $html;
        $html = '';
    }
}
```

[Test output](https://3v4l.org/JPbRa)

**Note:** 
When you have for example 11 items, you will miss the last 2.

If you also want to add the last 2, you could add this after the `while` loop which will check if `$html`  is not an empty string :

```
if ($html !== '') {
    $html .= "</div>\n";
    $output[] = $html;
}
```

[Output php](https://3v4l.org/1nBoa)

Comment: yes, it miss the last 2. can you tell how its get last 2 also?

Comment: @user3733831 I have updated my answer on how to include the last 2.

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
$output=[];    
$i=0; 
$html='';
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {    

  if($i % 3 == 0) {
    $html .= "<div class='row'>\n";
  }

$html .="<div class='col-sm-4'>
        <div class='room-box'>
          <img src='$thumb' class='img-responsive' >
          <h4>$name</h4>
        </div>
      </div>\n";

   if($i % 3 == 2) { 
      $html .= "</div>\n";
      $output[] = $html;
      $html = '';
   }
  $i++;
}
if($i%3!=0){
  $html .= "</div>\n";
  $output[] = $html;
  $html = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is mostly how you're trying to access the variables:

```
$output=[];    
$i=0; 
$html='';
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {    

  if($i % 3 == 0) {
    $html .= "<div class='row'>\n";
  }

  $html.="<div class='col-sm-4'>
            <div class='room-box'>
              <img src='{$row['thumb']}' class='img-responsive'>
              <h4>{$row['name']}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>\n";

  if ($i % 3 == 2) { 
    $html .= "</div>\n";
    $output[] = $html;
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Do the records have fields called `thumb` and `name`?